# Axios Get request issue

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I want when I click on the view button on Action column as below

[image]

It will be redirected to another page, which display a list containing the result of the Select query. The code is below :

**My router :**

```
exports.viewclient = function(req, res) {
  var Code = req.query.Code;
    console.log(req.params);

    connection.query('SELECT Code, Prenom, Nom, FAX, Telephone, Email, Adresse1, Adresse2  FROM clients  WHERE Code = ?',[req.params.Code],  function(error, results, fields) {
        if (error) throw error;
        res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
console.log(results);
    });

}
```

**My server :**

```
router.get('/viewclient/:Code', clients.viewclient);
```

**My handleView method on the class Liste :**

```
handleView(event) {
    try {

      console.log("Voir client")
      this.props.history.push('/clients/viewclient/' + this.state.Code);

    }
    catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }
```

**View Class :**

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients: [],
            Code: this.props.match.params.Code


        };
 componentDidMount() {


    axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' + this.state._code)

        .then(response => {
            if (response && response.data) {
                this.setState({ clients: response.data });
            }
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

When I run the backend with Postman `http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/1111` it returns `[{"Code":1111,"Prenom":"test","Nom":"test","FAX":"58985688888","Telephone":"58985699888","Email":"test@gmail.com","Adresse1":"","Adresse2":""}]`

But when I run my frontend, it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/app/viewclient/undefined` and I can't view the result of Select.

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Typo: `Code: this.props.match.params.Code` does not match `this.state._code`.

Comment: I edit it @Quentin and it works well as I post my answer, can you up the post for enabling post again questions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state looks like this:

```
this.state = {
  clients: [],
  Code: this.props.match.params.Code
};
```

but you call your state like this

```
this.state._code
```

The name for your state variable has to be the same so change your state variable or you call so they match:

```
this.state = {
  clients: [],
  Code: this.props.match.params.Code
};

axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' + this.state.Code)
```

Comment: When I put that on View Class, it returns :                                              
 `Request URL: http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/undefined
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 Not Modified
Remote Address: [::1]:4000
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Comment: HTTP Status Code 304 means `Indicates that the resource has not been modified since the version specified by the request headers If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match. In such case, there is no need to retransmit the resource since the client still has a previously-downloaded copy.`. Also what i forgot to mention you should call this on componentDidMount.

Comment: Yes, I put that on   `componentDidMount()` , but how  can I fix that please ?

Comment: Sorry typo: not in componentDidMount(), beacause there is no state available

Comment: I resolve it, as you see on my answer post, thank you @MaddEye

Answer (score 2):

On class View I edit :

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            clients: [],
            Code: props.match.params.Code
        };
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/viewclient/' + this.props.match.params.Code).then(function(response) {
            if (response.status >= 400) {
                throw new Error("Bad response from server");
            }
            return response.json();
        }).then(function(data) {
            if (data === "success") {
                this.setState({ msg: "User has been deleted." });
            }
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }
```

That make it works well.